# Alpha_Vantage ts.get_daily ending with [0]

Tags: python, alpha-vantage

I am learning how to use Alpha_Vantage api and came across this line of code. I do not understand what is the purpose of [0].

SATS = ts.get_daily('S58.SI', outputsize = "full")[0]

Answer (score 0):

`ts.get_daily()` appears to return an array.

SATS is getting the 0 index of the array (first item in the array)